# emacs, auctex, noweb-mode - how to keep screen from recentering around point?

Tags: emacs, r, sweave, auctex, noweb

When in auctex and noweb-mode (using Sweave in emacs), I find it distracting when the screen recenters itself as I use next-line, previous-line, etc. (C-n, C-p, and mouse-1). Does anyone know how to turn it off? Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got to `customize-group: windows` and read the documentation for `scroll-step` and `scroll-conservatively`. If you set `scroll-conservatively` to a big value you should get the behavior you want. I tried 10000. You can also have a look at [Info (emacs) Scrolling](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Scrolling.html#Scrolling).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Much better... kind of hackish but works well. Previously I had checked out the scrolling page in the elisp documents and searched for use of the reposition, recenter by noweb-mode.el but this scroll-conservatively eluded me.